# Selecting singular parts of an object

Tags: materials, select

Good day, I am going to add some material to a model of cabinet: instead of selecting single faces (which will take long time), is there any way to select components/elements (such as drawers, panels, etc.) in a faster way?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Thank you all for your answers,

I will try to explain you in a simpler way: as you can see from the image there is an beautician table which needs to be texturised.

Now, Imagine I want to select singular elements which compose the object like the mattress, the chassis or the paper roll: is there any way to do it without individually select every vertex/edge/face from them, but as single components?

[image]

Comment: You can try to select a face, or several faces, and press Shift G (Select Similar) > Area or Perimeter, is it what you want?

Comment: of course - in edit mode go to select -> components -> furniture -> doors (e.g.) ....:D sorry, couldn't resist

Comment: If a component is made of connected geometry and separate from other components, you can hover your mouse over it and press L, this selects linked geometry. Or if you have a face of a component selected, press Ctrl+L which selects linked geometry of the current selection.

Comment: @Chris.. it won't be long before AI accepts our voice-command to 'select drawers' and then does it for us, whilst muttering under its breath that our topology is s**t, and we'd be better off starting from scratch.

Comment: As I understand, this is not possible...I do apologise but I am a novice to Blender: I can perfectly do it manually, but I wondered since in the past I have been spending some time on 3ds Max (nothing remarkable) and I remember it was easier to select single elements - probably I am wrong.

Comment: @CarloVentimiglia Cunning combinations of Shift-G select similar.. progressive hiding, and Ctrl-numpad  + / - to expand or contract selections can usually get pretty quick results. Maybe share an object on https://blend-exchange.com/ for a demonstration.

Comment: I would really be immensely grateful if you can teach me how to do this: here is the link to the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=xoJB53yK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/xoJB53yK/)